# Coldfusion 11 Upgrade - web server configuration issue

Tags: iis, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

We just migrated from `ColdFusion 9` to `ColdFusion 11` and are facing the following issues while accessing the website hosted on `Windows 2003` `IIS 6`.

1. The website is hosted under `Integrated Windows Authentication` mode. While accessing the site with index.cfm at the end of the URL prompts for credentials and throws a `page cannot be displayed` error even if correct credentials are provided.

Excerpt from `isapi_redirect.log` debug logs.

> [debug] handle_notify_event::jk_isapi_plugin.c (2179): Filter started
>
> [debug] map_uri_to_worker_ext::jk_uri_worker_map.c (1170): Attempting
>   to map URI '//index.cfm' from 30 maps
>
> [debug] find_match::jk_uri_worker_map.c (984): Attempting to map
>   context URI '/*.CFML=cfusion' source 'uriworkermap'
>
> [debug] find_match::jk_uri_worker_map.c (984): Attempting to map
>   context URI '/*.Cfml=cfusion' source 'uriworkermap'
>
> .. .. .. .. .. [debug] find_match::jk_uri_worker_map.c (984):
>   Attempting to map context URI '/*.cfml=cfusion' source 'uriworkermap'
>
> [debug] find_match::jk_uri_worker_map.c (984): Attempting to map
>   context URI '/*.CFC=cfusion' source 'uriworkermap'
>
> [debug] find_match::jk_uri_worker_map.c (984): Attempting to map
>   context URI '/*.swc=cfusion' source 'uriworkermap'
>
> [debug] find_match::jk_uri_worker_map.c (984): Attempting to map
>   context URI '/*.CFM=cfusion' source 'uriworkermap'
>
> [debug] find_match::jk_uri_worker_map.c (984): Attempting to map
>   context URI '/*.cfc=cfusion' source 'uriworkermap'
>
> [debug] find_match::jk_uri_worker_map.c (984): Attempting to map
>   context URI '/*.cfm=cfusion' source 'uriworkermap'
>
> [debug] find_match::jk_uri_worker_map.c (997): Found a wildchar match
>   '/*.cfm=cfusion'
>
> [debug] handle_notify_event::jk_isapi_plugin.c (2261): check if
>   [/index.cfm] points to the web-inf directory
>
> [debug] handle_notify_event::jk_isapi_plugin.c (2278): [/index.cfm] is
>   a servlet url - should redirect to cfusion
>
> [debug] handle_notify_event::jk_isapi_plugin.c (2316): fowarding
>   escaped URI [/index.cfm]
>
> [debug] handle_notify_event::jk_isapi_plugin.c (2389): forwarding to :
>   /jakarta/isapi_redirect.dll
>
> [debug] handle_notify_event::jk_isapi_plugin.c (2391): forward URI   :
>   TOMCATURI6A6B0000:/index.cfm
>
> [debug] handle_notify_event::jk_isapi_plugin.c (2396): forward worker:
>   TOMCATWORKER6A6B0000:cfusion
>
> [debug] handle_notify_event::jk_isapi_plugin.c (2398): worker index  :
>   TOMCATWORKERIDX6A6B0000:28
>
> [debug] handle_notify_event::jk_isapi_plugin.c (2179): Filter started
>
> [debug] map_uri_to_worker_ext::jk_uri_worker_map.c (1170): Attempting
>   to map URI '//jakarta/isapi_redirect.dll' from 30 maps
>
> [debug] find_match::jk_uri_worker_map.c (984): Attempting to map
>   context URI '/flashservices/gateway/*=cfusion' source 'uriworkermap'
>
> [debug] find_match::jk_uri_worker_map.c (984): Attempting to map
>   context URI '/cfform-internal/*=cfusion' source 'uriworkermap'
>
> [debug] find_match::jk_uri_worker_map.c (984): Attempting to map
>   context URI '/cffileservlet/*=cfusion' source 'uriworkermap'
>
> [debug] find_match::jk_uri_worker_map.c (984): Attempting to map
>   context URI '/cfformgateway/*=cfusion' source 'uriworkermap'
>
> .. .. [debug] find_match::jk_uri_worker_map.c (984): Attempting to map
>   context URI '/*.jsp=cfusion' source 'uriworkermap'
>
> [debug] find_match::jk_uri_worker_map.c (984): Attempting to map
>   context URI '/*.cfm=cfusion' source 'uriworkermap'
>
> [debug] find_match::jk_uri_worker_map.c (984): Attempting to map
>   context URI '/*.as=cfusion' source 'uriworkermap'
>
> [debug] handle_notify_event::jk_isapi_plugin.c (2404):
>   [/jakarta/isapi_redirect.dll] is not a servlet url
>
> [debug] init_ws_service::jk_isapi_plugin.c (3494): Reading extension
>   header HTTP_TOMCATWORKER6A6B0000: (null)
>
> [debug] init_ws_service::jk_isapi_plugin.c (3495): Reading extension
>   header HTTP_TOMCATWORKERIDX6A6B0000: -1
>
> [debug] init_ws_service::jk_isapi_plugin.c (3496): Reading extension
>   header HTTP_TOMCATURI6A6B0000: (null)
>
> [debug] init_ws_service::jk_isapi_plugin.c (3497): Reading extension
>   header HTTP_TOMCATQUERY6A6B0000: (null)
>
> [debug] init_ws_service::jk_isapi_plugin.c (3502): No URI header value
>   provided. Defaulting to old behaviour
>
> [error] HttpExtensionProc::jk_isapi_plugin.c (2622): failed to init
>   service for request.

2. Running the page excluding index.cfm at the end runs fine.

Ex. http:///test/ works but http:///test/index.cfm doesn't.

Based on the Installation Guide for IIS Web Server configuration:

> i. Folder 1 has been created with all the connector-related files.
>   ii.`Jakarta` virtual directory is present for all the websites.
>   iii. Tomcat ISAPI filter is present.
>   iv. Handlers are present as well.

3. CGI.Path_Info is returning `[empty string]`. This issue was supposedly fixed in some version of CF 10.

Any pointers would be really helpful?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm unclear on whether or not you've added the jakarta virtual directory.  Have you? http://i.imgur.com/2czCBoH.png

Comment: @TRose : Yes, `Jakarta` virtual directory was added as part of `Web Server Configuration Tool`